# Did you know that we have flyers?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

So, I talked to our wonderful and amazing designer, [Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin), and he was kind enough to whip up a couple of flyers for me to post up here so that you all can use them! It's very exciting, I know. I have two versions: a more "feminine" version and a more "masculine" version.

[image: Dad Version] 
([Full size version](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37817961/flyer_parenting_dad.pdf).)

[image: Mom Version]
([Full size version](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37817961/flyer_parenting_mom.pdf).)

These are European A4 sized, which print nicely on North American paper sizes as well. You'll need Adobe Reader to open these up.

***If you have feedback, feel free to let me know!*** These aren't exactly carved in stone.

**[UPDATE]** -- Jin redid these to include tear-off slips, so I've reuploaded the images and files. :D

**[UPDATE 2]** -- If you have ideas that aren't centered on baby questions, feel free to post them as an answer!

Comment: Is there any interest in folks being able to order professionally printed heavyweight versions of these? I could pretty easily setup a gallery where folks could order them.

Comment: I'm interested to know how the questions were chosen.

Comment: @WilliamGrobman I searched for top questions that were as relevant to the images as they could be. :)

Answer (score 11):

Bravo! Great work. I'd like to register one bit of feedback (mentioned earlier on other channels):

Site users could print these and hang them up in lots of places (grocery store, kindergarten, public billboard, etc.). But given that parents are likely to not have the time or mental surplus to stop and write down that URL, nor memorize it, **it would be good to have a version with tear-off slips at the bottom,** containing just the site name and the question URL.

It would likely not be a lot of work to create a copy of the poster and add these slips. Both versions of the poster (i.e., with and without the tear-off slips) should be available though;  the current version with the URL in big letters is very useful in  situations where the slips aren't needed.

Also, why not throw in a QR code in a corner? [image: Cellphones can use this!] Cellphones can use this to jump to the URL encoded in the image. This one contains a short URL http://goo.gl/Pgyy5 which in turn points to http://parenting.stackexchange.com.
I used [goo.gl](http://goo.gl/) to create the short link, and [this site](http://goqr.me/) to create the image.

[Here's a mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3W6r.png) of what I had in mind. (Apologies to Jin!)

Comment: +1 Really good idea; I didn't even notice that at first.

Comment: I'm going to do tearoff slips in a separate layer under the poster when I run them off. My plan is to print the poster on a slightly heavier card stock I have, then I'll print the tear offs on cheap office paper, probably three rows of them, which I'll cut and layer then tape to the back of the poster. This way I can run off more slips and replenish the tear offs without having to reprint the whole poster. Now to just figure out where to put them. :)

Comment: pdf for tearoffs as I talked about: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2174935/parenting-staclexchange-tearoffs.pdf

Comment: That's a great idea. I should've thought of that. I'll make the slip version.

Comment: The flyer has now been updated to include slips! :D Thank you, @Jin!

Comment: ThankyouThankyouTHANKyou Jin!!

Comment: As an aside. http://s.tk/parenting works too, though it's still longer than your link :)

Answer (score 5):

I saw this banner

[image]

on Programming SE sidebar today. I'd say that it's a very good example of being nice and cute without being annoying and overly excited (many people find toddlers, diapers and especially parents' enthusiasm about those very annoying). So IMO it's very nice job done by the banner designer - conveys the right message and drags exactly the right amount of attention.