# Does anyone know why Parenting got ads in the sidebar?

Tags: discussion

I've been seeing ads for Parenting in the sidebar of various StackExchange sites recently, even though Parenting is only in beta.  Does anyone know why/how this happened?  The ads seem to be based on the images posted in [this thread](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257/did-you-know-that-we-have-flyers).

Comment: I don't believe site promotion is normally limited to graduated sites.  Beta sites frequently receive promotional activities, ranging from contests to ad space.

Comment: So they can make money ... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the regular [site promotion](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-promotion), I think most SE sites do that kind of thing.